# How to get rid of invalid identifier

Tags: sql, oracle

I have this update :

```
update myTable set myColumn = "VP:" || "001" || " " || "12/2016";
```

as a result of a program.

I have an error with "12/2016". Oracle says it is not a valid identifier. Why is that ?

Note : size of myColumn : 14

Comment: Why not just say `set myColumn = 'VP:001 12/2016'` - or is this not your actual code?

Comment: use ticks instead of quotes?

Comment: String values are specified with single quotes in SQL, not double quotes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Am not a expert in Oracle, but double quotes are used for `Identifiers`(db objects). Use single quotes for `strings`

```
update myTable set myColumn = 'VP:' || '001' || ' ' || '12/2016';
```

If this is your actual code then, no need of string concatenation here. It can be simplified to

```
update myTable set myColumn = 'VP:001 12/2016'
```

Comment: Or simpler: `'VP: 001 12/2016'`;

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - updated it in answer. Thanks